# Find top 2 row in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i can already combine 2 same facilities_id, but i wan the quantity also combine together. How to solve it?

How to find the top 2 row in gridview based on the quantity? Thanks

```
facilities_id    name      date        quantity
   F001           aa    12Jan2014      1
   F001           aa    12Jan2014      12
   F002           bb    14Jan2014      1
   F003           cc    15Jan2014      1
```

i hope output can become like this.

```
facilities_id   name      date        quantity

  F001           aa    12Jan2014      13
  F002           bb    14Jan2014      1
  F003           cc    15Jan2014      1 

    DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();


    var query = from p in db.Facilities
                join v in db.Reservations on p.facilities_id equals v.facilities_id
                join c in db.Reservation_Details on v.reservation_id equals  
                c.resevation_id

                where SqlMethods.Like(c.date, "%" + DropDownList1.Text + "%")
                select new
                {
                    p.facilities_id,
                    p.name,
                    c.date,
                    Quantity = p.Reservations.Count()

                };



    GridView1.DataSource = query.GroupBy(x => x.facilities_id)
                     .Select(g => g.First())
                     .ToList();
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you do this even before binding to the grid? Looks like you want to group by the first 3 columns and want a sum in the end. So why not do this before returning the data to the UI level? Anyways,  if you want to do groupby in your code, it should be something like this. I have never tried to bind anonymous to a grid, so you **might** need a strongly typed object instead of anonymous object.

```
GridView1.DataSource = query.GroupBy(x => x.facilities_id)
                     .Select(g => new 
                           {g.Key, g.First().name, 
                              g.First().date, g.Sum(gg=>gg.Quantity)}) 
                      .ToList();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: g.Sum(gg=>gg.Quantity)}) this part have underline, what problem is that?